# Multiple entity context and identity use for migrations and data seed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have currently on my Api 2 connections strings, one with limited rights used as main context for the whole application and the other with more rights used only for migrations and data seed.

I am currently blocked on how to use the Identity Api stores on a specific context.

For example when i'm on my seed data i'm using the UserManager and RoleManager and i need to be binded to the "admin" context to do my operations.

On my startup I binded the identity stores on a specific context:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser<int>, IdentityRole<int>>(opt =>
{
    opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    opt.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

From some topic i saw it doesn't work to add multiple store, the consequences is the DI container inject only the first added, for example if i do:

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MigrationContext>()
```

The Di container expose only the first declared (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/525697/a-way-to-having-multiple-aspnet-core-identities-pe.html) the answer on the topic isn't applicable to my case unfortunatly.

I'm searching to switch the context i use in function of the use case.

Comment: Does that mean you have one context for development mode and another context for production?

Comment: Not exactly, I have one context with elevated rights for read write on database and another context only for read who is used in my controllers

Comment: Are your two Contexts both related to IdentityDbContext?